# Unexpected token ILLEGAL when mixing classic javascript with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this javascript code which ran fine so far :

```
<div id="freewall" class="free-wall"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var temp = "<a class='fancybox' rel='group' href='graphics/tattoos/hd/{index}.jpg'>
              <div class='brick' style='width:{width}px;'>
                <img src='graphics/tattoos/sd/{index}.jpg' width='100%'>
              </div>
            </a>";
var w = 1, h = 1, html = '', limitItem = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < limitItem; ++i) {
    w = 1 + 3 * Math.random() << 0;
    html += temp.replace(/\{width\}/g, w*150).replace(/{index}/g, i + 1);
}
$("#freewall").html(html);

var wall = new Freewall("#freewall");
wall.reset({
    selector: '.brick',
    animate: true,
    cellW: 150,
    cellH: 'auto',
    onResize: function() {
        wall.fitWidth();
    }
});

var images = wall.container.find('.brick');
images.find('img').load(function() {
    wall.fitWidth();
});
</script>

var wall = new Freewall("#freewall");
wall.reset({
    selector: '.brick',
    animate: true,
    cellW: 150,
    cellH: 'auto',
    onResize: function() {
        wall.fitWidth();
    }
});

var images = wall.container.find('.brick');
images.find('img').load(function() {
    wall.fitWidth();
});
</script>
```

You can see the result at : http://rimetattoo.com/index.php?p=tattoos

I am rewriting this website using AngularJS (mostly for training), and put the same code in a template being used as a view. When I run the app in Chrome, I get an exception "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" in angular.js:12330.

I am pretty new to Angular and I am supposing that something must be wrong in the syntax I am using there, because when I remove this script, everything is okay.

Can somebody give me a heads up on what is going on there ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Notice : when i use the standard freewall flexgrid example in the view, everything runs fine. The only differences in my version compared to the out-of-the-box version is that I am replacing multiple instances of {index} using /{index}/g instead of "{index}"

Comment: That code should error on the new line in the string literal at the top. The live demo you link to do not show any errors.

Comment: Quentin, you are my savior, I formatted this string for visibility purpose and didn't think a second that I was editing a string literal... Thank you so much.